# Issue with org-mode export to pdf via LaTeX

Tags: org-mode, org-export, pdf

Whenever I export my org-mode (version 8.2.10) file to pdf via LaTeX, it gives me:

**Page 1** with only content `2015/01/01Old fixltx2e package 0000/00/00Old fixltx2e package` and the rest part is blank.

**Page 2 onwards** normal expected content but with raster fonts.

Edit:

My .org file header:

```
#+LaTeX_CLASS: article
#+LaTeX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [12pt]
#+LaTeX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [a4paper]
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[hyperref,x11names]{xcolor}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=SteelBlue4,linkcolor=Firebrick4]{hyperref}
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \usepackage{mathpazo}
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \linespread{1.05}
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \usepackage{courier}
#+OPTIONS: H:2 email:t |:t
#+TITLE: To-do List
#+TODO: TODO(t@/!) URGENT(u) | DONE
```

I checked the .tex file auto-generated before the pdf generation. However, the corresponding .tex file generated from my .org file has the package \usepackage{fixltx2e} though the .org file doesn't have any such package.

Header of the autogenerated .tex from my .org file:

```
% Created 2018-03-29 Thu 22:24
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fixltx2e} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\tolerance=1000
\usepackage[hyperref,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=SteelBlue4,linkcolor=Firebrick4]{hyperref}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\linespread{1.05}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
\author{xyz@abc.com}
\date{\today}
\title{To-do List}
\hypersetup{
  pdfkeywords={},
  pdfsubject={},
  pdfcreator={Emacs 25.2.1 (Org mode 8.2.10)}}
```

There appears some error with `fixltx2e.sty` file.

[image: Log Issues]

Below is the screenshot of the first page of the org exported pdf as generated.

[image: screenshot of the first page of the org exported pdf]

Zoomed view of the aforesaid scrrenshot.

[image: Zoomed view of the aforesaid scrrenshot]

Comment: Try exporting to a latex file with `C-c C-e l l` and then running `pdflatex` (or whatever) on the file from the command line. That should at least tell you whether the problem is the export or not. If you still cannot figure it out, then add to your question a minmal org file that exhibits the problem and the resulting tex file, so that people can try it out. Also mention the org-mode version you are using (`C-x org-version RET` will tell you).

Comment: you can't compile a LaTeX `.sty file`, so don't worry about the errors that you see when you try to do that for `fixltx2e`.

Comment: But the first page with error text annoys me. How to get rid of that permanently?

Comment: At least in `org mode 9.1.9`, the `fixltx2e` package has been removed from the default configuration.  This package is no longer need on upto date LaTeX installations, as the relevant parts of the code have now been included into the LaTeX core.

Answer (score 1):

The package fixltx2e is now declared obsolete, but it is still part of org-mode default configuration. It is part of org-latex-default-packages-alist variable. Can be deleted from that variable by customizing it: type C-h v, then the variable's name and RET.

Comment: How can I customise it? It would be great if you can explain. Being Emacs noob, it would take sometime for me to understand all these jargon. ELI5

Comment: Completed the response.

Comment: I have updated the org package. This solved the problem. Thanks for your inputs.